# Using Jmeter with Okta SSO

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, load-testing, stress-testing, okta

I'm trying to do performance testing on a web app which has Okta SSO enabled, so basically I get login screen wherein I add username and password, then it redirects me to a page where I have to write security pin, the caveat is that the pin is of 6 digits, and Okta randomly asks to write any 2 digits from my pin, unless I do that I can't login to the web app. Good news is, in my recorded scripts I see `pinDigits` which are actually the digits that Okta asked for so there has to be a way to capture that `pinDigits` value, please refer screenshot below -

[image]

Now I want to capture that `pinDigits` value and store my full 6 digit pin in an array, then once I have the value, I can pass the digit on the basis of index of the array to `pin` parameter from screenshot above.

Answers are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For getting assistance on "capturing pingDigits value" you need to provide full (or at least partial) response from Okta and your [Post-Processor configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which does not work. It is not code-writing-for-free service and I have strong doubts regarding each community member having an application with Okta authentication installed somewhere. A swiss army knife solution for extracting "interesting" part of the response would be [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. With regards to storing `pinDigits` into an array just create 6 separate [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   pinDigit_1=9
   pinDigit_2=8
   pinDigit_3=7
   pinDigit_4=6
   pinDigit_5=5
   pinDigit_6=4
   ```

   So you will be able to refer 1st digit using `${__V(pinDigit_1)}`, 2nd digit using `${__V(pinDigit_2)}`, etc.

   If you will have another JMeter Variable holding Okta response, i.e. `oktaDigit` the syntax to get the combined variable would be like `${__V(pinDigit_${oktaDigit})}`.

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)